# Return inside parentheses value in a string as integer in Java

Tags: java, regex

I extracted format information from cobol copybook and need to use a switch or if statement to get the value inside ( ). All values are in an array of string and I am iterating array with the sample values below.

```
X(37)
9(03)
X(15)
9(07)
X
X(1)
X(253)
```

my switch case

```
private int convertSize(String pic) {
    switch (pic) {      
    case "X" :
        return 1;
    case "X("+ "string inside" +")" :
        return Integer.parseInt("string inside");
    case "9("+ "string inside" +")" :
        return (Integer.parseInt("string inside")+1);
    default:
        return 0;
    }
```

what should I replace with "string inside" to get the result? 
"\d+" won't work because it is saved as string in arrays.

Comment: Well, for a start, if the `"string inside"` part is going to be variable, you can't use `switch` for this in Java (or most other languages, JavaScript being one of the few exceptions). So you'll be looking at a different structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go.  Fully unit tested...

```
package com.example;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Question28819604 {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Assert.assertEquals(37,convertSize("X(37)"));
        Assert.assertEquals(4,convertSize("9(03)"));
        Assert.assertEquals(15,convertSize("X(15)"));
        Assert.assertEquals(8,convertSize("9(07)"));
        Assert.assertEquals(1,convertSize("X"));
        Assert.assertEquals(1,convertSize("X(1)"));
        Assert.assertEquals(253,convertSize("X(253)"));
        Assert.assertEquals(0,convertSize("non-match"));
        Assert.assertEquals(0,convertSize(null));
        Assert.assertEquals(0,convertSize("X(broken)"));
        Assert.assertEquals(0,convertSize("X(broken"));
    }

    private Pattern xPattern = Pattern.compile("X\\((\\d+)\\)");
    private Pattern ninePattern = Pattern.compile("9\\((\\d+)\\)");

    private int convertSize(String pic) {
        if (pic == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        Matcher xPatternMatcher = xPattern.matcher(pic);
        Matcher ninePatternMatcher = ninePattern.matcher(pic);

        if ("X".equals(pic)) {
            return 1;
        } else if (xPatternMatcher.matches()) {
            return Integer.parseInt(xPatternMatcher.group(1));
        } else if (ninePatternMatcher.matches()) {
            return Integer.parseInt(ninePatternMatcher.group(1)) + 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a working code with example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(convertSize("X(37)"));
        System.out.println(convertSize("X."));
        System.out.println(convertSize("X(9941)"));
    }

    private static int convertSize(String pic) {
        try {
            String myNumberInString = pic.substring(pic.indexOf("(")+1, pic.indexOf(")"));
            int myNumberInInteger = Integer.valueOf(myNumberInString);
            return myNumberInInteger;
        } catch (Exception e){
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

The output of this progam will be

```
37
0
9941
```

Your approach with switch is not possible in this case.

Comment: This doesn't handle the 9(07) case.

Comment: @DonaldW - It does, it returns 7 as you were asking for.

Comment: The point is, it's supposed to return 8, not 7.

Comment: @DonaldW - lol? You said : `get the value inside ( )`, so this is doing exactly you were asking for.

Comment: I didn't say anything.  I just read the question fully :)

Comment: @DonaldW - You did, let me cite your whole sentence : `I extracted format information from cobol copybook and need to use a switch or if statement to get the value inside ( ).`

Comment: It is not my sentence.  It is not my question. ...

Comment: @DonaldW - oh, true :D, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution (you still have to check for Exceptions!)

The Pattern can be compiled once (as part of the Class initialization)

```
private int convertSize(String pic) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\((\\d+)\\)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(pic);
    if (m.find()) {
        if(pic.startsWith("9")) {
            return Integer.valueOf(m.group(1)+1);
        } else if(pic.startsWith("X")) {
            return Integer.valueOf(m.group(1));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this going to recognize \\d+ ? Since the array is with string not integer

Comment: @KodS yes.. `\d+` is meant to be used with Strings.

Comment: This doesn't handle the 9(07) case.